# How to make lives in the python game pacman?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a very basic game of Pac man. I almost finished it but I am not aware how can I add lives and high score features in the script. I actually tried a lot of resources and tutorials but none of them helped me

main.py

```
import pygame

from game import Game


#screen size
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

def main():
    pygame.init()
    global livesRemaining

    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT)) 
    # Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
    
    pygame.display.set_caption("PACMAN")

    # Set the current window caption

    done = False
    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # to manage how fast the screen updates
    
    game = Game()
    # Create a game object
    
    
    
    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        done = game.process_events()
        game.run_logic()

        game.display_frame(screen)
        
        clock.tick(30)
        # --- Limit to 30 frames per second
        
        #tkMessageBox.showinfo("GAME OVER!","Final Score = "+(str)(GAME.score))
    # Close the window and quit.
    # If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit if running from IDLE.
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

player.py

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    explosion = False
    game_over = False
    def __init__(self,x,y,filename):
        # Call the parent class (sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.health = 3
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
        # Load image which will be for the animation
        img = pygame.image.load("walk.png").convert()
        # Create the animations objects
        self.move_right_animation = Animation(img,32,32)
        self.move_left_animation = Animation(pygame.transform.flip(img,True,False),32,32)
        self.move_up_animation = Animation(pygame.transform.rotate(img,90),32,32)
        self.move_down_animation = Animation(pygame.transform.rotate(img,270),32,32)
        # Load explosion image
        img = pygame.image.load("explosion.png").convert()
        self.explosion_animation = Animation(img,30,30)
        # Save the player image
        self.player_image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.player_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

    def update(self,horizontal_blocks,vertical_blocks):
        if not self.explosion:
            if self.rect.right < 0:
                self.rect.left = SCREEN_WIDTH
            elif self.rect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
                self.rect.right = 0
            if self.rect.bottom < 0:
                self.rect.top = SCREEN_HEIGHT
            elif self.rect.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
                self.rect.bottom = 0
            self.rect.x += self.change_x
            self.rect.y += self.change_y

            # This will stop the user for go up or down when it is inside of the box

            for block in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,horizontal_blocks,False):
                self.rect.centery = block.rect.centery
                self.change_y = 0
            for block in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,vertical_blocks,False):
                self.rect.centerx = block.rect.centerx
                self.change_x = 0

            # This will cause the animation to start
            
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.move_right_animation.update(10)
                self.image = self.move_right_animation.get_current_image()
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                self.move_left_animation.update(10)
                self.image = self.move_left_animation.get_current_image()

            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.move_down_animation.update(10)
                self.image = self.move_down_animation.get_current_image()
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.move_up_animation.update(10)
                self.image = self.move_up_animation.get_current_image()
        else:
            if self.explosion_animation.index == self.explosion_animation.get_length() -1:
                pygame.time.wait(500)
                self.game_over = True
            self.explosion_animation.update(12)
            self.image = self.explosion_animation.get_current_image()
            

    def move_right(self):
        self.change_x = 3

    def move_left(self):
        self.change_x = -3

    def move_up(self):
        self.change_y = -3

    def move_down(self):
        self.change_y = 3

    def stop_move_right(self):
        if self.change_x != 0:
            self.image = self.player_image
        self.change_x = 0

    def stop_move_left(self):
        if self.change_x != 0:
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.player_image,True,False)
        self.change_x = 0

    def stop_move_up(self):
        if self.change_y != 0:
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player_image,90)
        self.change_y = 0

    def stop_move_down(self):
        if self.change_y != 0:
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.player_image,270)
        self.change_y = 0



class Animation(object):
    def __init__(self,img,width,height):
        # Load the sprite sheet
        self.sprite_sheet = img
        # Create a list to store the images
        self.image_list = []
        self.load_images(width,height)
        # Create a variable which will hold the current image of the list
        self.index = 0
        # Create a variable that will hold the time
        self.clock = 1
        
    def load_images(self,width,height):
        # Go through every single image in the sprite sheet
        for y in range(0,self.sprite_sheet.get_height(),height):
            for x in range(0,self.sprite_sheet.get_width(),width): 
                # load images into a list
                img = self.get_image(x,y,width,height)
                self.image_list.append(img)

    def get_image(self,x,y,width,height):
        # Create a new blank image
        image = pygame.Surface([width,height]).convert()
        # Copy the sprite from the large sheet onto the smaller
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet,(0,0),(x,y,width,height))
        # Assuming black works as the transparent color
        image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        # Return the image
        return image

    def get_current_image(self):
        return self.image_list[self.index]

    def get_length(self):
        return len(self.image_list)

    def update(self,fps=30):
        step = 30 // fps
        l = range(1,30,step)
        if self.clock == 30:
            self.clock = 1
        else:
            self.clock += 1

        if self.clock in l:
            # Increase index
            self.index += 1
            if self.index == len(self.image_list):
                self.index = 0
```

enemies.py

```
import pygame
import random

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color,width,height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)


class Ellipse(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color,width,height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        # Draw the ellipse
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image,color,[0,0,width,height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)

        
class Slime(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,change_x,change_y):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Set the direction of the slime
        self.change_x = change_x
        self.change_y = change_y
        # Load image
        self.image = pygame.image.load("slime.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
 

    def update(self,horizontal_blocks,vertical_blocks):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.left = SCREEN_WIDTH
        elif self.rect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = 0
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.rect.top = SCREEN_HEIGHT
        elif self.rect.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = 0

        if self.rect.topleft in self.get_intersection_position():
            direction = random.choice(("left","right","up","down"))
            if direction == "left" and self.change_x == 0:
                self.change_x = -2
                self.change_y = 0
            elif direction == "right" and self.change_x == 0:
                self.change_x = 2
                self.change_y = 0
            elif direction == "up" and self.change_y == 0:
                self.change_x = 0
                self.change_y = -2
            elif direction == "down" and self.change_y == 0:
                self.change_x = 0
                self.change_y = 2
                

    def get_intersection_position(self):
        items = []
        for i,row in enumerate(enviroment()):
            for j,item in enumerate(row):
                if item == 3:
                    items.append((j*32,i*32))

        return items
    
        
def enviroment():
    grid = ((0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0),
            (0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0))

    return grid

def draw_enviroment(screen):
    for i,row in enumerate(enviroment()):
        for j,item in enumerate(row):
            if item == 1:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE , [j*32, i*32], [j*32+32,i*32], 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE , [j*32, i*32+32], [j*32+32,i*32+32], 3)
            elif item == 2:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE , [j*32, i*32], [j*32,i*32+32], 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE , [j*32+32, i*32], [j*32+32,i*32+32], 3)
```

game.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from enemies import *
from player import Player

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 576

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,40)
        self.about = False
        self.game_over = True
        # Create the variable for the score
        self.score = 0
        # Create the font for displaying the score on the screen
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,35)
        # Create the menu of the game
        self.menu = Menu(("Start","About","Exit"),font_color = WHITE,font_size=60)
        # Create the player
        self.player = Player(32,128,"player.png")


        # Create the blocks that will set the paths where the player can go
        self.horizontal_blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.vertical_blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # Create a group for the dots on the screen
        self.dots_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # Set the environment:
        for i,row in enumerate(enviroment()):
            for j,item in enumerate(row):
                if item == 1:
                    self.horizontal_blocks.add(Block(j*32+8,i*32+8,BLACK,16,16))
                elif item == 2:
                    self.vertical_blocks.add(Block(j*32+8,i*32+8,BLACK,16,16))


        # Create the enemies
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemies.add(Slime(288,96,0,2))
        self.enemies.add(Slime(288,320,0,-2))
        self.enemies.add(Slime(544,128,0,2))
        self.enemies.add(Slime(32,224,0,2))


        # Add the dots inside the game
        for i, row in enumerate(enviroment()):
            for j, item in enumerate(row):
                if item != 0:
                    self.dots_group.add(Ellipse(j*32+12,i*32+12,WHITE,8,8))



        # Load the sound effects
        self.pacman_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_sound.ogg")
        self.game_over_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("game_over_sound.ogg")




    def process_events(self):
        global livesRemaining
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
                return True
            self.menu.event_handler(event)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if self.game_over and not self.about:
                        if self.menu.state == 0:
                            # ---- START ------
                            self.__init__()
                            self.game_over = False
                            livesRemaining -= 1
                            player()
                        elif self.menu.state == 1:
                            # --- ABOUT ------
                            self.about = True
                        elif self.menu.state == 2:
                            # --- EXIT -------
                            # User clicked exit
                            return True

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player.move_right()

                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.player.move_left()

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.player.move_up()

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.player.move_down()
                
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.game_over = True
                    self.about = False

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player.stop_move_right()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.player.stop_move_left()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.player.stop_move_up()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.player.stop_move_down()

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.player.explosion = True
                    
        return False

    def run_logic(self):
        if not self.game_over:
            self.player.update(self.horizontal_blocks,self.vertical_blocks)
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.dots_group,True)
            # When the block_hit_list contains one sprite that means that player hit a dot
            if len(block_hit_list) > 0:
                # Here will be the sound effect
                self.pacman_sound.play()
                self.score += 1
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.enemies,True)
            if len(block_hit_list) > 0:
                self.player.explosion = True
                self.game_over_sound.play()
            self.game_over = self.player.game_over
            self.enemies.update(self.horizontal_blocks,self.vertical_blocks)
           #tkMessageBox.showinfo("GAME OVER!","Final Score = " + str(GAME.score))

    def display_frame(self,screen):
        # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        # --- Drawing code should go here
        if self.game_over:
            if self.about:
                self.display_message(screen,"Developed by Hooda Abdul Shakoor")
                #"a maze containing various dots,\n"
                #known as Pac-Dots, and four ghosts.\n"
                #"The four ghosts roam the maze, trying to kill Pac-Man.\n"
                #"If any of the ghosts hit Pac-Man, he loses a life;\n"
                #"the game is over.\n")
            else:
                self.menu.display_frame(screen)
        else:
            # --- Draw the game here ---
            self.horizontal_blocks.draw(screen)
            self.vertical_blocks.draw(screen)
            draw_enviroment(screen)
            self.dots_group.draw(screen)
            self.enemies.draw(screen)
            screen.blit(self.player.image,self.player.rect)
            #text=self.font.render("Score: "+(str)(self.score), 1,self.RED)
            #screen.blit(text, (30, 650))
            # Render the text for the score
            text = self.font.render("Score: " + str(self.score),True,GREEN)
            # Put the text on the screen
            screen.blit(text,[120,20])
            
        # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()

    def display_message(self,screen,message,color=(255,0,0)):
        label = self.font.render(message,True,color)
        # Get the width and height of the label
        width = label.get_width()
        height = label.get_height()
        # Determine the position of the label
        posX = (SCREEN_WIDTH /2) - (width /2)
        posY = (SCREEN_HEIGHT /2) - (height /2)
        # Draw the label onto the screen
        screen.blit(label,(posX,posY))


class Menu(object):
    state = 0
    def __init__(self,items,font_color=(0,0,0),select_color=(255,0,0),ttf_font=None,font_size=25):
        self.font_color = font_color
        self.select_color = select_color
        self.items = items
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(ttf_font,font_size)
        
    def display_frame(self,screen):
        for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
            if self.state == index:
                label = self.font.render(item,True,self.select_color)
            else:
                label = self.font.render(item,True,self.font_color)
            
            width = label.get_width()
            height = label.get_height()
            
            posX = (SCREEN_WIDTH /2) - (width /2)
            # t_h: total height of text block
            t_h = len(self.items) * height
            posY = (SCREEN_HEIGHT /2) - (t_h /2) + (index * height)
            
            screen.blit(label,(posX,posY))
        
    def event_handler(self,event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if self.state > 0:
                    self.state -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if self.state < len(self.items) -1:
                    self.state += 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. `Game` should have variables `self.lives` and `self.highscore`. When you detect collision then you do `self.lives -= 1` and check `if  self.lives > 0`. And if it is zero then you finish game and you check `if current_score > self.highscore: self.highscore = current_score`

Comment: so what is the problem? Do you get error ? Show it in question (not in comments). Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. And we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question (not in comments)